# how to implement a distributed system for a monitoring platform

Tags: c#, design-patterns, distributed-system

I am having some trouble implementing the right patterns for a work project and I don't want to precede until I am satisfied with the right design strategy.

The project is based around *Genesys Computer Telephony Integration (CTI) Platform*. Essentially, utilizing a SDK provided by Genesys, a single client subscribes to a number of Genesys services (or *TServers*) running remotely. The client then registers a whole heap of Directory Numbers (DN's) associated to a particular *TServer* and waits for call events. When an event occurs, it is captured by the client and stored in a database. A number of other operations are executed, which is irrelevant at this stage. A lot of the communication work is handled by the Genesys **ProtocolManager** object, so a single event handler captures event data across all clients, which in turn is handled by a **EventBrokerService**. Here is a simple code to illustrate the connection process, registration of a single DN and the event function:

```cs
        EventBrokerService eventBrokerService;

        using (var client = new TServerProtocol(
            new Endpoint(
                new Uri("tcp://tserver01:11234"))))
        {
            client.Open();

            eventBrokerService = BrokerServiceFactory.CreateEventBroker(client);
            eventBrokerService.Activate();
            eventBrokerService.Register(this.OnEvent);

            RequestRegisterAddress requestRegisterAddress = 
                    RequestRegisterAddress.Create("977845873", 
                                                  RegisterMode.ModeMonitor, 
                                                  ControlMode.RegisterDefault, 
                                                  AddressType.DN);
            IMessage response = client.Request(requestRegisterAddress);
        }
```

and then we listen for events (there are many different events):

```cs
    private void OnEvent(IMessage response)
    {
        switch (response.Id)
        {
            case EventACK.MessageId:
                //do something
                break;
            case EventLinkConnected.MessageId:
                var ev = response as EventLinkConnected;
                //Insert event into DB and perform some other operations...
                break;
        }
    }
```

The Genesys Platform, comes with another component called a Genesys Configuration server. The config server holds all of the TServer details, including the DN information and a whole bunch of other "objects". It is really just a fancy DBMS. The difference is, you can also subscribe to the config server and register for CRUD events (i.e. **CreateEvent**, **UpdateEvent** etc...). Without illustrating the code, the concept is similar to the one above. (i.e. You can register to a number of different Configuration Servers and listen for CRUD events).

For the most part, I have covered the above well and I am satisfied with the implementation so far. What I am trying to achieve is as follows:

I am attempting to implement a distributed system. In a nutshell, the system will consist of 2 components. Monitoring Services and Dispatcher Service components (they will all be Windows Services)

**Monitoring Service Component**

- The "Monitoring Service(s)" connect to 1 or many T Servers to monitor for call events
- The monitoring service will **ALSO** subscribe to a dispatcher service

**Dispatcher Service Component**

- The "Dispatcher Service" connects to 1 or more Configuration Servers and waits for CRUD events.
- Once an event occurs (i.e. a new DN was added on the config server), the dispatcher captures the creation event, and notifies all monitoring service subscribers. Subsequently, the dispatcher will also update a local database, so the DN information is preserved for redundancy (in case dispatcher can not connect to a Configuration Server).
- The monitoring subscriber, to whom the newly created DN belongs (distinguished by a unique DBID and TServerID identifiers) will accept the DN, and register it for listening events (similarly illustrated in the first code snippet). The monitoring subscriber who does not possess the required TServer connection will drop the received request, naturally.
- The Dispatcher can also receive newly added TServers, but this time around, it will make the decision which monitoring service it want's to utilize in order for that monitoring service to make ANOTHER connection. This will be determined by factors such as the number of current sessions running on a monitoring service or the how much memory a single service is chewing up at the time.

I have come up with some basic concepts and here is some of the code to illustrate what I have done thus far:

The communication method I have chosen is WCF with **NetTcpBinding**, so for the simple part, I have exposed an interface:

```cs
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "urn:Netwatch", 
                 SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, 
                 CallbackContract = typeof(IDisMonServiceCallback))]
public interface IDisMonService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Subscribe(string uid);
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Unsubscribe(string uid);
}

[ServiceContract(Namespace="urn:Netwatch")]
public interface IDisMonServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool DNRegistered(int tServerId, string dnEntry);
}
```

and on the dispatcher, I have implemented it:

```cs
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class DisMonService : IDisMonService
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, IDisMonServiceCallback> subscribers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IDisMonServiceCallback>();

    public IDisMonServiceCallback this[string uid]
    {
        get
        {
            IDisMonServiceCallback callback;
            if (!subscribers.TryGetValue(uid, out callback))
                return null;
            return callback;
        }
    }

    public List<IDisMonServiceCallback> GetAllServiceCallbacks()
    {
        return new List<IDisMonServiceCallback>(subscribers.Values);
    }

    public bool Subscribe(string uid)
    {
        IDisMonServiceCallback callback = GlobalHelper.Callback<IDisMonServiceCallback>();

        if (!subscribers.ContainsKey(uid))
            if (!subscribers.TryAdd(uid, callback))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(string uid)
    {
        IDisMonServiceCallback callback;

        if (subscribers.ContainsKey(uid))
            if (!subscribers.TryRemove(uid, out callback))
                return;
        return;
    }
}
```

From the code above, it is obvious that each subscribing monitoring service has a unique identifier, that way the right service callback context is retrieved (in case I decide to do some other funky operations).

This is where my dilemma essentially begins. To cut the long story short, my question(s) are as follow:

1. How do I deal with **DisMonService** class when attempting to pass on messages to all subscribers from within the Dispatcher service. i.e. new DN has been added, let us call the **DisMonService** class and notify all subscribers.
2. What would be the most optimal pattern to implement in dealing with updates to all subscribers from within **DisMonServie**

At the moment my dummy client connects to the dispatcher, and it registers itself. Moving forward, what is the best way to access the **DisMonService** class.

I hope I am not confusing anybody at what I am trying to ask. I guess what I am really trying to find is best way to implement the above system, any suggestions and such. Some code samples and snippets would really be helpful.

This is my first post here so I apologise to anybody if I haven't explained myself to the forum's standards.

Comment: I don't understand a few things. First, what better way to access a WCF service than with a WCF client? Second, what criteria is `GlobalHelper.Callback<>()` using to determine what value to return?